Driving a LED matrix with TPIC6B595 as sink and UDN2981A as current source
I am working with an 8x6 RGB LED matrix with common cathode LEDs on a PCB. I can select one column at a time by grounding its common cathode, and I source the current through the rows. The whole setup is controlled using 4x74HC595 chained shift registers.
Since there are 8 columns, the LEDs can only shine at 1/8th of their capacity due to multiplexing. After some tests, I realized that for a satisfactory result, the LEDs need to be driven at their full capacity, i.e., at least 15mA. Unfortunately, after burning a few 74HC595 ICs, I discovered that they cannot source or sink that much current reliably.
For the sinking part (columns), I decided to replace the 74HC595 controlling the columns with a TPIC6B595, which seems well-suited for this purpose.
My question is about the sourcing part (rows), where I am more uncertain. I understand that I need to use NPN transistors between the shift registers and the rows to handle the current. To reduce the number of components, I found an IC (UDN2981A) that appears to integrate the transistor circuitry I need.
Here is the planned circuit configuration. Is this the correct way to use the UDN2981A for this purpose?
Notes: Red output have 140 ohm resistor in series, while blue and green have 220 ohm resistors in series.


The schematic mentions UDN2981A, which is plausible, but title and text talk about UDN2081A, which probably does not exist.

The UDN2981 is obsolete although it looks like Microchip still make the equivalent MIC2981. Your circuit configuration should work but I’d suggest some level translation from the STM32 3V logic to the HC595 5V logic. Many manufacturers have specific LED driver ics that are probably cheaper than one MIC2981 and do the multiplexing and individual current control as well. I used some devices from TI recently that made for a simpler design.

@Jens My mistake indeed, I fixed the title.

@Kartman Thanks for the answer. That explain why I found it so hard to find any documentation or example using UDN2981. Your point regarding the different logic level used may also explain some dysfunctions when testing the setup... I will need to had some IC for level shifting. The reason I chose to avoid using a more "automated" IC is that the LED matrix is also coupled with a button matrix, so I need to read the input at the same time that I'm updating the leds (leds and buttons both share the same ground).

After thoughs another solution may be to use 3.3V as VCC for every IC, and adjust the led resistors accordingly.

Have you simulated the circuit?

@Anvently the TI LP5860 will scan a keypad as well. It’s not a documented feature but since it can detect whether a given LEDs current is in range means it will detect a switch. This has been confirmed by TI and I’ve had it work. It also does the level translation for you. It’s in a QFN package but it can be hand soldered with a small tip and some flux.

@liaifat85 No, not really familiar with circuit simulation TBH. I prefer to do tests on breadboard as I have a few 74hc595s on hand and had already bought some UDN2981.

@Kartman Arf...  The TI LP5860 really looks like a game killer for what I'm trying to do. Well as I have already ordered the DIP parts, I'll do some testing this week with what I have, and if it doesn't work as expected, I'll consider using it. Though I'm not sure to understand what you meant by using it to detect button switch. Reading the datasheet, I didn't understand that the IC could send inputs to an MCU, which is what I need.

@Anvently. The chip has the ability to detect if a led has failed, not inserted or working. Replace a led on the matrix with a switch and it will detect a short circuit when the switch is pressed. You can read this status from registers. The mcu communicates via I2C or spi and can read/write registers in the LP5860.

I conducted tests today, and based on the feedback from my previous post, I decided to power the circuit with 3.3V instead of 5V as shown in the initial schematic. Only the UDN2981A chips are powered with 5V on VCC, but their input pins are compatible with 3.3V signals.
Here is the updated schematic:

Everything works as expected, and I am satisfied with the results.
Some notes:

I added decoupling capacitors to the power pins of all the chips.
Upon reviewing the 74HC595 datasheet, it is recommended not to leave unused outputs floating, so I connected them to ground.
I included series resistors for the LEDs, calculated to drive approximately 20mA per LED (25-30mA for the red LED to compensate for its lower perceived brightness).
It is also recommended to connect unused inputs of the UDN2981A to ground through 10k resistors.

Additional notes:
As Kartman pointed out, there are more modern components that integrate both the shift register and the capability to drive the required current without needing external transistors.
The TI LP5820 combines the entire circuit into a single component and even offers additional features, but it is not available in a DIP package.
